# Any structural issues when creating an 11" diameter hole in brick wall?

Tags: brick, ventilation

I'd like to install an external blower for a range hood. Spec says an 11" diameter. I have a 12" thick brick wall. I'm wondering if there are any structural issues with making a hole that big.

The wall is the exterior kitchen wall with no structure above it (ie, just the roof).

Comment: 12" thick brick wall? That number seems high unless you're living in an old bunker

Comment: By brick do you mean cinder block?

Answer (score 2):

Not if you cut it round - using a diamond hole saw so that the edges are all clean. Done properly the mortar joints won't be disturbed and the bricks around the hole will support themselves.

If, however, you just "hack" a rough opening with a chisel and sledge then you will crack all the mortar joints around and it could easily be or become unstable.